# Way in solidity to match users address with address defined in array

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am looking for an efficient way to check if the the person invoking a function is allowed to access a function defined in a smart contract by comparing msg.sender with array of addresses that I am hardcoding at the time of deployment in solidity. I can do it using for loop but that takes a lot of gas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At first I was tempted to tell you there's no way around it, but then I got intriguing idea and it turned out to work out pretty well! ***Note however, that this will only work in case you know the addresses at compile time.***

**Note:** In my experiment, I've modified the task a bit - I will be comparing msg.sender to list of blacklisted addresses. Changing this to your usecase is straightforward.

### Intuitive solution

The intuitive way to implement the functionality you are proposing would be probably following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DataInStorage {

    uint counter;

    address[] public blackListed = [ 0x281055afc982d96fab65b3a49cac8b878184cb16, 0x6f46cf5569aefa1acc1009290c8e043747172d89 ]
    function increment() public {
        for (uint i=0; i<blackListed.length; i++) {
            require(msg.sender != blackListed[i]);
        }
        counter += 1;
    }

}
```

The gas costs turned out to be following:

```
<number of addresses>   |  <gas spent>
100                     |  124808
200                     |  207708
```

So it seems that the cost of one iteration is about 829 (`829 * 100 = 82900 = 207708 - 124808`)

### Why is this expensive?

First of all, why is iterating addressed and comparing them to msg.sender expensive? It's not because of the for `loop`, it's not because of the `if` comparisons. The reason is that EVM needs to **read** from contract storage. Reading and writing to storage are the most expensive operations.

### Contract code vs Contract storage

So here comes the idea. What if we don't put these addresses into contract storage, but contract code instead? Let's give it a try

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DataInCode {

    uint counter;

    function increment() public {
        require(0x281055afc982d96fab65b3a49cac8b878184cb16 != msg.sender);
        require(0x6f46cf5569aefa1acc1009290c8e043747172d89 != msg.sender);
        counter += 1;
    }

}
```

I've tried this pattern with higher number of addresses, and here's an interesting result

```
<number of addresses>   |  <gas spent>
100                     |  45338
200                     |  49038
```

**So one address verification costs us in this case only 37 gas. That's about 22 times better than the solution with contract storage.**

If someone can provide more technical explanation why loading code in EVM is much cheaper than loading data storage, I would love to hear it.

### Full example

Data In Code (100 addresses) https://ethfiddle.com/mDB9OM2azy

Data In Code (200 addresses) https://ethfiddle.com/nIt2QwBLTX

Data In Storage (100 addresses) https://ethfiddle.com/Wg5CMAN0OU

Data In Storage (200 addresses) https://ethfiddle.com/5NVVCVUT0R

Tested with Truffle

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation :) . It was really helpful.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach. Not only is it a nightmare to look at in code, you’ve made the list immutable. Also, for gas comparisons, you’re right that it’s cheaper when comparing to iterating over an array, but you’re neglecting the difference of gas at deployment time. The better solution is to use a `mapping` populated at deploy time, updateable via a transaction, and checked in a modifier (`require(myMap[msg.sender])` where `myMap` is a `mapping(address -> bool)`)

Comment: @AdamKipnis you are absolutely right. Please, post your solution as an answer, I will delete mine to keep things clean.

Answer (score 1):

Use mapping to store this.

```
mapping(address => bool) public blacklisted;
```

...

```
require(!_blacklisted[msg.sender]);
```

You could also use it as a modifier:

```
  modifier notBlacklisted() {
    require(!blacklisted[msg.sender]);
    _;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

then in a function:

```
function foo() notBlacklisted public
{
  // do stuff
}
```

only users who are not blacklisted will be able to use the function.